# how to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject for values without name

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a json string like this:
{"status":false,"data":{"errors":{"":"error45"}}}

I cant make a class for this json string, because the last part has no name => ""

I test this class:

```
public class Result
{
    public bool status { set; get; }
    public ResultDetail data { set; get; }
}

public class ResultDetail
{
    public ErrorDetails errors { set; get; }       
}

public class ErrorDetails
{        
    public string abc { set; get; }
}
```

but abc returns null !!!!

Comment: Add this to `abc` -> `[JsonProperty("")]`

Comment: I dont think that is valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Dictionary<string, string>` for the errors.

```
public class Result
{
    public bool status { set; get; }
    public ResultDetail data { set; get; }
}

public class ResultDetail
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> errors { set; get; }
}
```

and use the following to deserialize and access the dictionary.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
Console.WriteLine(result.data.errors.Values.FirstOrDefault());
```

Or you can assign the value to a variable

```
obj.data.errors.TryGetValue("", out string error);
Console.WriteLine(error);
```

I will mention this as well that the property names should be Proper names (first letter Capital). To be able to deserialize properly, use the `[JsonProperty("corresponding_json_key")]` to each of your properties of your classes to conform to C# standards.

```
public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public bool Status { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public ResultDetail Data { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! Im beginner in C#! when I wrote [JsonProperty("data")], I got the error: "the type or namespace jsonproperty couldnt be found! or when I wrote Dictionary, I got the same error for it. Please help me, what should I do?

Comment: You need to include `using Newtonsoft.Json` directive on top. Make sure you have newtonsoft json package installed as well

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It was helpful

Comment: how can I use Dictionary instruction? I have error in using it, yet!